# Creating a password for a console application in c++

Tags: c++, conio

I am trying to make a simple program as an application for what I learned, I am trying to make a program that takes a password from the user and for each character the user puts, there is an '*' is shown in the console and when he press enter key the program stops taking more characters and show the password again so I use a string to store each character

This is my code:...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;
    
int main(){
    int i=0;
    string password;
    char p;
    cout << "Password: ";
    do{
        p = getch();
        cout.put('*');
        password[i] = p;
        ++i;
    } while (p != '\n');
    cout << "Your password is : " << password;
return 0;
}
```

[When I run the program it remains taking characters and never stops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAA6m.png)

[also when I exit the console window it shows a message like this :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqkTZ.png)

So what is the solution?!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `password[i] = p` is Undefined Behavior because the string `password` is empty. You probably want `password += p;`.

Answer (score 1):

- When you press Enter key, not `'\n'` (LF) but `'\r'` (CR) will be read via `getch()`.
- You are accessing elements of the string without allocating them.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;
    
int main(){
    string password;
    char p;
    cout << "Password: ";
    do{
        p = getch();
        cout.put('*');
        password.push_back(p); // note: '\r' will also be appended
    } while (p != '\r');
    cout << "Your password is : " << password;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to avoid copy-paste the code above, if in case @MikeCat code does not work use \r\n as Windows uses it to signify the enter key was pressed, while Linux and Unix use \n to signify that the enter key was pressed you can also check them by their ASCII codes value (decimal or hex) which is 10 for \n and 13 for \r and 0x0D0A for \r\n.

so you can either check by -if you are in windows and I assume that-

```
while (p != '\r\n');
```

or by using ASCII code try

```
while (p != 10); // \n
```

or

```
while (p != 13); // \r
```

or

```
while (p != 0x0D0A); // \r\n
```